# Iron router not redirecting to proper url

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router

I've written some code that allows someone to submit a form, then an email method gets called, and the user is redirected to another page. Here's the code:

```
Template.home.events({
  'click .send': function () {
    var fromEmail = $(".fromEmail").val();
    var toEmail = $(".toEmail").val();
    var amount = $(".amount").val();
    var sessionId = Meteor.uuid();
    var sessionLink = "http://myurl:3000/id/" + sessionId
    Meteor.call("sendEmail", fromEmail, toEmail, amount, sessionLink);
    Router.go("/id/" + sessionId + "/begin"); // changed this
  }
});
```

So when I click submit, the email method gets called, but when I get redirected, I get redirected to http://myurl.com:3000, not http://myurl.com:3000/id/fa6a2c8c-a6aa-4bc7-8ca3-a5903166831b which is what it should be redirecting to. What's the reason for this?

Edit:
Here is what my router looks like:

```
Router.map( function () {
  this.route("home", {
    path: "/"
  });
  this.route("payment", {
    path: "/id/:id"
  }); 
  this.route("session", {
    path: "/id/:id/begin"
  }); 
});
```

Comment: What does your route, and your route controller if you've added one, look like?

Comment: Edited my original post with the router code. The templates they go to are just regular templates with a few lines of html in them.

Comment: Everything is in a form that's posted? Try running `event.preventDefault()` (`event` comes as the first parameter to the function) when the form is posted.

Comment: yes, it's just html with a bunch of inputs that gets posted. Where would you want me to put ``` event.preventDefault() ``` ?

Comment: Here's what I had to do to fix it. Not sure exactly why it was breaking in the first place still, but I edited my original post with the updated code.